# How to recoil camera up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I make the camera recoil up? I don't think it uses a coroutine when moving the camera up. please help.....

The recoil back and forward was made using coroutine and Lerp like this,

```
Vector3 recoilBack = new Vector3(currentGun.retroActionForce, originPos.y, originPos.z); 
Vector3 retroActionRecoilBack = new Vector3(currentGun.retroActionFineSightForce, currentGun.FineSightOriginPos.y, currentGun.FineSightOriginPos.z);

if(!isfineSightMode)     
{         
    currentGun.transform.localPosition = originPos; // start recoil back and forward         
    while(currentGun.transform.localPosition.x <= currentGun.retroActionForce - 0.02f)         
    {             
        currentGun.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(currentGun.transform.localPosition, recoilBack, 0.4f);
        yield return null;         
    }         //  back to place
    while(currentGun.transform.localPosition != originPos)
    {             
        currentGun.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(currentGun.transform.localPosition, originPos, 0.1f);
        yield return null;         
    }     
}
```

The code above is the code that recoils back and forward.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the recoil code as shown works ok for the gun, then no extra code is needed; all you need to do is parent the camera to the gun and it will work fine. Don't forget to align the forward vector of the camera with the gun if you want to see along the barrel.

(Improvement note: the lerp will give a constant recoil motion, which is not very realistic; you should use an animation curve instead and then you can tune the motion to your needs).

(Editing to reflect that the camera is attached to the player and not the gun)

In the script that does the gun recoil, give it a public reference to a camera and then assign the main camera to it in the inspector. Once you have done that, you can move the camera relative to the player using whatever method you prefer.

```
[SerializeField]
public Camera cam;
```

then in whatever part of the script fires the gun:

```
cam.transform.localPosition = 'whatever you want it to be'
```

Also, I would not use a coroutine for this (preferably not for anything). much better to use the Update method (as long as your script is a monobehaviour) and set the motion using Time.deltaTime() so that the motion adjusts itself to the frame rate of the game.

Comment: I think that for your second point, perhaps using exponential increase or decrease would work, but you would still use the lerp function even though it is not linear.

Comment: @pyjamaslug  What I set up in the hierarchy is the state where the main camera is put inside the player, and I want to make recoil up to use value of camera. what can I do??

Comment: @pyjamaslug I'm trying to code to raise the camera up using the rotation value. ```private void CameraUp()
    {
        theCam.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(theCam.transform.localEulerAngles, theCam.transform. // , 0.2f);
    }``` Is that right way?? What more do I need to add?

Comment: I think you need to step back and look at what you are trying to do. The problem you are addressing involves much more than just coding. There is no quick fix. I faced this when I started working with unity about five years ago and even with a twenty year history of graphics behind me, it was still difficult. 
You must read and understand much more of what you want to do and then you will be more prepared for the task.